# Stringize __VA_ARGS__ (C++ variadic macros)

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, stringification, variadic-macros

Let's have

```
class Item{
public:
    Item(int id,const char *name,const char *props=NULL);
};
```

And I want to write:

```
ITEM(1,FIRST);
ITEM(2,SECOND, WithSomeProps);
```

With a macro

```
#define ITEM(ID,NAME,...) new Item(ID,NAME, #__VA_ARGS__ )
```

That `#__VA_ARGS__` compiles well on gcc but gives an error on VStudio. Is there a solid and portable solution?

I want to have a collection of `ITEM()` in a .h file that will be included several times with different #definitions of `ITEM`.

Comment: Why would you want to do this over just typing `new Item( ID, NAME, OTHER_ARGS )`?

Comment: Why do you need this? since third input argument of the constructor is defaulted you can call `Item(1, FIRST)` and `Item(2, SECOND, WithSomeProps)`.

Comment: Why the wild `new` hidden behind a macro?

Comment: Dubious motives not withstanding, I find it interesting whether stringization of the `__VA_ARGS__` pseudoargument is standard CPP.

Comment: @KerrekSB, It definitely is. At first sight check out § 16.3.5/9.

Comment: The actual use is a bit more complex and I thought to make a simple example of what I wanted to achieve and clarify the possibility.

Comment: ... always post the real code that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0):

GCC and Visual Studio handle Variadic Macros differently, because Macros are based on the compiler preprocessor (they are expanded at preprocessing time).

One of the difference is how they handle the empty variadic macros.
One of them will allow empty `__VA_ARGS__` while the other will cause a compiler error if the `__VA_ARGS__` is empty.

On your example the first the line `ITEM(1,FIRST)` will cause an error at compile time, while working ok on the other .

One workaround for this is to have an empty first argument, so your constructor will be something like :

```
Item(int id,const char *name,void *allwaysNull, const char *props=NULL);
```

And then have your Macro initialziations like this

```
ITEM(1,0,FIRST)
ITEM(2,0,SECOND,WithSomeProps)
```

What is weird is that from my experience it was GCC that was having problems with empty `VA_ARGS` for variadic macros...

Comment: Is **VA_AGS** a mistype?

Comment: Hi @MIchaelCMS I haven't tried but it seems that your ida would overcome the problem with the missing emtpy argument but what I can not see is how this may help to stringize VA_ARGS